# I need a best effective way for Node.js API Versioning

Tags: node.js, api-versioning

I need a best effective way for Node.js API Versioning.

Answer (score 1):

## REST API versioning

#### URL versioning

You can use routes named with versions

- https://exapmpleapi/v1/...

### Custom request header

You can create a new request header that contains the version.

- Accept-version:v1
- Accept-version:v2

### Using accept header

You can use accept request header with the versions.

- Accept :application/example.comv;version:1.0

## For code

You can use github or gitbucket..

### using npm modules

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-api-versioning

Comment: any effective npm packages ?